# Add custom certificate for iphone HTTP API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, https

Is there any way to bundle a certificate in my application - and then use that to perform HTTP GET/POST using a `NSURLRequest`?

I.e. the certificate should not be used for other HTTP traffic on the device, only by my application.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, but since all applications are sandboxed any special authentication measures you may have within your application cannot be accessed by other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Best (in my opinion) you put the private key and certificate that you want to use on the keychain (or keychains of other 3rd party apps that share the same provisioning certificate).

As for the actual loading of the p12 we do use openssl (we did write a obj-c wrapper around it) to decode the .p12 that we send to the app (you can always use .DER or .PEM to ship the p12 with your app)